# Civi is Requiring "On Behalf of Organization" fields when that's not even checked

Tags: civicontribute, error, forms

On our contribution form, we allow people to contribute "On Behalf of an Organization" however it's not required.

The problem is even when that box is left unchecked, they get to the confirmation page without error, but when they actually click to submit the form, it says that the organization fields are all required.

It looks like this person had a similar problem.
https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=35137.0

Here's our form:
http://rivertreesingers.org/support

If you test it, just check the mail a check option to go through, but it shouldn't let you complete.

If it seems like a bug, where should that be reported? I'm on CiviCRM 4.7.3 in a WordPress environment.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers? I had someone report the same thing on their server, but I can't replicate it.

Answer (score 1):

Never did find a good solution. We ended up just removing the option from the form. At the time, I think we misunderstood how CivicCRM works and what the purpose of "on behalf of an organization" was. One thing we learned though, that might help you. The organization in question has to already exist in the database. I think that is still true for the latest versions of CiviCRM.

Anyway, we just tell donors that if they want to contribute "as an organization" (note the wording: not "on behalf of an organization" but rather, "as an organization"), then they need to use a corporate credit card or a corporate bank account. That way, the organization entity gets the tax credit, not the individual. Civi assumes that the donor is an individual. Always, so far as I know. So, if the donor in filling out the online form is "representing" a corporate entity, that's fine. Can do that. But the payer, usually as indicated by the payer address (the billing address associated with the credit card), is the one that the IRS will look for if they ever audit. Of course, you can set it up so that the person filling out the form gets a "soft credit" whereas the actual payer (the organization) gets the hard credit. Hope this helps.

Comment: Civi assumes that individuals have fingers and can type and that organisations do not ;-). An afaik, there is no presumption that the Org must already exist, it can be created on the fly. Civi then creates a 'permissioned' 'current' employee of relationship with the org. And the latter means that if the individual uses a checksum (or logs in) then the Org details will automatically show on the form.

Comment: Thanks, John. I went ahead and removed it for now. The weird thing is before I upgraded to the newest version of CiviCRM, it worked fine. We had someone, make a contribution on behalf of his organization, which was new to the database and it took it fine and triggered the emails, etc.

When I disabled it, I was able to successfully submit a contribution, but it didn't send the email even though other emails like event registrations are working.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question "where should a bug be reported" - you should go to https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/login.jsp

But, in general you should not open a new Question if one already exists, so you may find this question gets voted down or deleted.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find this question on this new StackExchange Q/A site. The place I saw it was on the forum where the Q/As are being deprecated. The thread was unresolved and over a year old, and it didn't look like I could reply to it any more.